# Laravel: Accessing Path Function in Model in Index File

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have set up the following function in my model:

```
  public function path() {
    return route('news.show', ['id' => $this->id, 'slug' => $this->slug]);
  }
```

I would now like to access that function in my `index.blade.php` file -- like this:

```
  @foreach ($articles as $article)
  <a href="{{ $article->path() }}">
    // rest of code goes here
  </a>
  @endforeach
```

But when I try this, I get the following error:

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Missing required parameters for [Route: news.show] [URI: news/{id}/{slug}]. (View: C:\laragon\www\startup-reporter\resources\views\news\index.blade.php)
```

Here is what my routes (web.php) looks like:

```
Route::get('news', 'NewsController@index')->name('news.index');
Route::get('news/create', 'NewsController@create')->name('news.create');
Route::get('news/{id}/{slug}', 'NewsController@show')->name('news.show');
Route::get('news/{id}/edit', 'NewsController@edit')->name('news.edit');

Route::post('news', 'NewsController@store')->name('news.store');
Route::put('news/{id}', 'NewsController@update');
```

And here is my controller:

```
  // Index
  public function index() {
    $news = News::latest()->get();
    return view('news.index', ['articles' => $news]);
  }

  // Show
  public function show(News $id) {
    return view('news.show', compact('id'));
  }
```

Any idea why this is not working and what I need to do to get this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the link of show page? like `news/1/abc`

Comment: This `Route::get('news/{id}/{slug}', 'NewsController@show')->name('news.show');` vs. this `public function show(News $id) {` which error states.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes file you have defined 2 parameters, {id} and {slug}.

But in your controller you have only accepted 1 parameter, $id.

You should amend your show controller method like this:

```
// Show
public function show(News $id, $slug) {
  return view('news.show', compact('id'));
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you @Moshe ?